# tgreenplumrow-Join and Filter is not woking

Tags: talend, greenplum

When i try to execute Multiple Queries in tgreenplumRow component.
It is not allowing me Join and Filter queries.

Input Info

Source and target table both in greenplum only

Source table - Pointing the External source called HDFS

Target TABLE - regular table in greenplum database

Like this

**SQL Transaction**

```
Begin;
"insert into target_tbl (select S.* from source_tbl s "LEFT JOIN" target_tbl d ON s."PK"=d."PK" where d."PK" is null) ;

UPDATE target_tbl d
SET
"COL" = s."COL"
FROM source_tbl s 
WHERE s."PK"=d."PK" and d."COL" != s."COL"
;
END;
```

**Error I Get:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

**Actual Data Flow is**

```
              tgreenplumconnection
                        |
tjdbcinput -->tmap -->thdfsoutput -->tgreenplumrow -->tgreenplumcommit
```

**Q1:**  How to run multiple queries with Join and filter in txxxROW component.

**Q2:** Is that possible to Handle above  Source and target file scenario in tmap ?

Any Help on this would be much appreciated  ?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of tgreenplumrow component and the query in that component?

Comment: Screenshot attached in  question itself

Comment: By mistake while editing it appears. otherwise I tried with double quote only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to break these queries into separate components. In your case you want to turn off auto commit on the connection. 
So after that mapping you have 2 greenplumRows and 1 commit component.

I think this makes the code more easier to understand and debug, because right now you don't know whether insert or update throws an error.

Don't forget to escape the \ and double quotes with a \ character. I think that what is giving you trouble here.

t*row just simply passes the query that you write in to the database.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It is working for me when i inserted \"  instead of ".

Comment: Can i get how many rows Inserted /Updated in this flow after tgreenplumrow component.

Comment: If you create your own then yes. I proposed to Talend that we should have NB_LINES for all the row components, and somewhere we have a feature request for that for the last 2 years or so....

Comment: NB_LINES var is applicable to t*row .or only for t*output components

Comment: I know man, I ended up forking many of the components. I created a custom GPRow and a "tFlowLogger" component so I can insert the results into the log tables. It doesn't matter how you move the data between 2 tables, you want to know the records moved. Talend should have this by default.

Answer (score 1):

In tgreeenplumrow component, you have to simply have the queries in between double quotes like

```
"Begin;
insert into target_tbl (select S.* from source_tbl s LEFT JOIN target_tbl d ON s.PK=d.PK where d.PK is null) ;

UPDATE target_tbl d
SET
COL = s.COL
FROM source_tbl s 
WHERE s.PK=d.PK and d.COL != s.COL;
END;"
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: Yes I tried in double quote and giving the same error.

Comment: t*row family of talend component supports Join ?